# Retrieve TextAd using Adwords Api

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to retrieve TextAd (Headline,Desc1,Desc2,Display URL and Destination URL) and i failed.

This is my Code on retrieving Text ad it returns Null result

```
TextAd text = new TextAd();
System.out.println("Headline:"+text.getHeadline());
Syso... etc.
```

I want to retrieve All details of TextAd , I'm using java.

This is my the code for adding TextAd

```
 public static void runExample(
  AdWordsServices adWordsServices, AdWordsSession session, long adGroupId) throws Exception {
// Get the AdGroupAdService.
AdGroupAdServiceInterface adGroupAdService =
    adWordsServices.get(session, AdGroupAdServiceInterface.class);

// Create text ads.
TextAd textAd1 = new TextAd();
textAd1.setHeadline("Luxury Cruise to Mars");
textAd1.setDescription1("Visit the Red Planet in style.");
textAd1.setDescription2("Low-gravity fun for everyone!");
textAd1.setDisplayUrl("www.example.com");
textAd1.setFinalUrls(new String[] {"http://www.example.com/1"});

TextAd textAd2 = new TextAd();
textAd2.setHeadline("Luxury Cruise to Mars");
textAd2.setDescription1("Enjoy your stay at Red Planet.");
textAd2.setDescription2("Buy your tickets now!");
textAd2.setDisplayUrl("www.example.com");
textAd2.setFinalUrls(new String[] {"http://www.example.com/2"});

// Create ad group ad.
AdGroupAd textAdGroupAd1 = new AdGroupAd();
textAdGroupAd1.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);
textAdGroupAd1.setAd(textAd1);

// You can optionally provide these field(s).
textAdGroupAd1.setStatus(AdGroupAdStatus.PAUSED);

AdGroupAd textAdGroupAd2 = new AdGroupAd();
textAdGroupAd2.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);
textAdGroupAd2.setAd(textAd2);


// Create operations.
AdGroupAdOperation textAdGroupAdOperation1 = new AdGroupAdOperation();
textAdGroupAdOperation1.setOperand(textAdGroupAd1);
textAdGroupAdOperation1.setOperator(Operator.ADD);
AdGroupAdOperation textAdGroupAdOperation2 = new AdGroupAdOperation();
textAdGroupAdOperation2.setOperand(textAdGroupAd2);
textAdGroupAdOperation2.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

AdGroupAdOperation[] operations =
    new AdGroupAdOperation[] {textAdGroupAdOperation1, textAdGroupAdOperation2};

// Add ads.
AdGroupAdReturnValue result = adGroupAdService.mutate(operations);

// Display ads.
for (AdGroupAd adGroupAdResult : result.getValue()) {
  System.out.println("Ad with id  \"" + adGroupAdResult.getAd().getId() + "\"" + " and type \""
      + adGroupAdResult.getAd().getAdType() + "\" was added.");
}
```

}

How can i retrieve Those values from adwords.
this is my selector for retrieving the data from adword

```
SelectorBuilder builder = new SelectorBuilder();
Selector selector = builder
    .fields(AdGroupAdField.Id, AdGroupAdField.AdGroupId, AdGroupAdField.Status,
            AdGroupAdField.Description1,AdGroupAdField.Description2,AdGroupAdField.Headline)
    .orderAscBy(AdGroupAdField.Id)
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    .equals(AdGroupAdField.AdGroupId, adGroupId.toString())
    .in(AdGroupAdField.Status, "ENABLED", "PAUSED", "DISABLED")
    .equals("AdType", "TEXT_AD")
    .build();
```

Comment: Can you provide any further code? There isn't much happening here, so would expect the headline to be null. All I can see is happening is you are creating a new empty object and then expecting it to have values?

Comment: Actually i have no idea on how to get the Headline,Desc1/2 of the specific ad Group. if you could provide an example i will really appreciate it. 

Main question: How can i retrieve The Headline etc. of my TextAd

Comment: Your question is very broad. I think you need to go and check out how to use the Adwords API first: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries

Comment: I know how to use it. im just confused on how to get the Headline etc. of a textad. i can only get the Display URL of the textAd.

Comment: It seems you need to populate your TextAd object from the API and then you will be able to get property values. By saying 'new TextAd()' you will be getting an empty object. This can't be all of your code?

Comment: I added some of codes. so you can understand what i am asking. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecast adGroupAd.getAd() to TextAd then you can get headline and other methods.

```
TextAd textAd = (TextAd)adGroupAd.getAd();
textAd.getHeadline();
```